CocoaPods Error: [!] No podspec found for 'share_plus' in Flutter iOS Project
I'm working on a Flutter project with iOS integration, and I'm facing an issue when running pod install in the ios/ directory. I'm trying to use the share_plus package, but I keep getting the following error:
[!] No podspec found for 'share_plus' in
Steps I've taken so far:

I’ve verified that share_plus is listed in my pubspec.yaml:

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  share_plus:


Ran flutter clean and flutter pub get, followed by cd ios and pod install.

Added pod 'share_plus', :path => '.symlinks/plugins/share_plus/ios' in the ios/Podfile, but no luck.


